# how do I make it so that I can select stuff in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

I am having a hard time selecting more then one object in Edit Mode and can't figure out how to. but I've seen tutorials that are able to. I am using Blender 2.79.

Comment: You could at least include Blender version you use and add a screenshot of where do you have a problem. Selecting in Edit mode is very basic, in 2.8 it's just hold and drag left mouse button to select. In 2.79 it was pressing B or C first. Edit your question please with more information

Comment: Being able to edit multiple objects at a time is a new feature available in 2.8

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on this question [Can not select faces or edges in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149042/can-not-select-faces-or-edges-in-2-8)

You can select different objects in the project explorer or go back out to object mode (use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to switch between the 2 modes).

In edit mode, use the hot keys <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> for vertices, edges, faces respectively.