# Can not select faces or edges in 2.8

Tags: faces

Trying to learn blender using 2.8.  Using the book Blender Quick Start Guide.  Stopped at the start because I can't select faces or edges, only vertices. How do I make it select faces?

Comment: In edit mode, press `1` `2` `3` on your keyboard (not numpad)  can switch between vertex, edge, face select mode.

Comment: Thank you - what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

There are icons to the right of the Edit Mode option box.

You can also use the hot keys `1` for vertices, `2` for edges and `3` for faces.

Next time don't give up so quickly

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution is to turn off the toggle X-Ray (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> ). In *X-Ray Mode*, one sees through the faces, thus cannot select them.